# Is waitforseconds in a coroutine related to sephamore.WaitForSignal?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, rendering, profiler

I have been having major performance issues involving Sephamore.WaitForSignal. In the profiler it is taking up 22ms of cpu time. I have seen multiple threads with no solution. I have an idea, but need confirmation on whether or not it's related. In quite a few of my scripts I have coroutines with "yield return new WaitForSeconds() written in them. Is there any chance that this could be related to the Sephamore.WaitForSignal? My performance was relatively fine a few days ago, this issue just came into existence. Thanks!

My Profiler https://gyazo.com/935514d3eeeb1a4c9012a4383ce264fd

My Profiler 2  https://gyazo.com/dc936ab02d98e3c5080fe4d1d57d26d9

Comment: Have you tried if it goes away if you don't start these coroutines?

Comment: Could this be related to [High Quality Volumetrics](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/srp-vr-performance-is-significantly-worst-using-single-pass-instanced-compared-to-multi-pass-rendering) ?